# Delete Item from Array in Angular at Index value

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Maybe simple but, I am trying to delete item from an array of objects in Angular, But my current code only returns an *undefined* in the console as i'm sure it's not finding the right index value. It is also for a Kendo Grid. So I need to Splice based on what the user clicks, not a specific id. Link to demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fl5jde-xbsuno

data structure is:

```
export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Element 1"
  },
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Element 2"
  },
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Element 3"
  },
];
```

ts file

```
  public gridData: any[] = data;

  public removeItem(id) {
    let index = data.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
    if (index !== -1) {
      data.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(id)
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: So It kind of does, I can understand the concept, where I need to find the Index value and splice based on that, but the example you pointed to shows if the index value was '5' and splice on that, where as I need to splice based on what the user clicks

Comment: Can you please create the same issue in a sample Stackbliz project and provide a link so that it would be helpful to answer ?

Comment: Updated the link in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is that you pass nothing to `removeItem`. So, in your html I just wrote `removeItem(dataItem)` instead of `removeItem(id)`. In the ts the change is `let index = data.findIndex(e => e.id === dataItem.id);`.

Please check the updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fl5jde-3pb7ef?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the dataItem, like this:

```
<button
   kendoButton
   look="flat"
   [icon]="'delete'"
   (click)="removeItem(dataItem)"
 >
</button>
```

And then remove from this.gridData.

.ts

```
 public removeItem({id}) {
    this.gridData = data.filter(e => e.id !== id);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter, which is a JavaScript method:

```
  public removeItem(id) {
    this.gridData = this.gridData.filter(el => el.id != id)
    console.log(this.gridData)
  }
```

checkout the [documentation for filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

checkout the [Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wcwtd4?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: there is no difference between gridData before and after the filter ?

Comment: I have added the link to a stackblitz in the question so you can see.

Comment: @Sole I added a live demo to my answer too

Comment: @Sole the problem is `(click)="removeItem(id)"` I can see you don't have any `id` defined in the template